# tDOM not parsing the XML

Tags: tcl, tdom

I have this `XML` sample template from a command line output,

```
<config xmlns="http://tail-f.com/ns/config/1.0">
  <random xmlns="http://random.com/ns/random/config">
    <junk-id>1</junk-id>
    <junk-ip-address>1.2.2.3</junk-ip-address>
    <junk-state>success</junk-state>
    <junk-rcvd>158558</junk-rcvd>
    <junk-sent>158520</junk-sent>
    <foobar>
      <id1>1</id1>
      <id2>1</id2>
    </foobar>
  </random>
</config>
```

I need to extract the value of `junk-state` from this `XML`.

I made a `.tcl` script to run on this with a variable and using single quotes *just* for testing purposes as below,

Below are contents of my script. I just tried looping around the nodes, but with no success.

```
set XML "<config xmlns='http://tail-f.com/ns/config/1.0'>
      <random xmlns='http://random.com/ns/random/config'>
        <junk-id>1</junk-id>
        <junk-ip-address>1.2.2.3</junk-ip-address>
        <junk-state>success</junk-state>
        <junk-rcvd>158558</junk-rcvd>
        <junk-sent>158520</junk-sent>
        <foobar>
          <id1>1</id1>
          <id2>1</id2>
        </foobar>
      </random>
    </config>"


set doc [dom parse $XML]
set root [$doc documentElement]
set mynode [$root selectNodes "/config/random" ]

 foreach node $mynode{
    set temp1 [$node text]
    echo "temp1 - $temp1"
 }
```

The above script produces no output,

Also tried a direct `xpath` expression as below and print text

```
set node [$root selectNodes /config/random/junk-state/text()]
puts [$node nodeValue]
puts [$node data
```

and this produces an error

```
invalid command name ""
    while executing
"$node nodeValue"
    invoked from within
"puts [$node nodeValue]"
    (file "temp.tcl" line 41)
```

What am I doing wrong here. Like to know how use/modify my `xpath` expression, since I find that neater.

```
$ tclsh
% puts $tcl_version
8.5
% package require tdom
0.8.3
```

Comment: The problems are due to the XML namespaces (`xmlns` attributes in the `config` and `random` elements). You must use the  `-namespace` option of `selectNodes` operation.

Comment: @Leon: Thanks for the response, I figured out the attributes were the reason, but could not solve the problem. Would you be kind enough to show it as a answer, how to extract `junk-state` here?

Comment: `set mynode [$root selectNodes -namespace {x http://random.com/ns/random/config} x:random/x:junk-state ]` will resolve `mynode` to the `<junk-state>` element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problems are due to the XML namespaces (`xmlns` attributes in the `config` and `random` elements). You must use the `-namespace` option of `selectNodes` operation:

```
package require tdom
set XML {<config xmlns="http://tail-f.com/ns/config/1.0">
      <random xmlns="http://random.com/ns/random/config">
        <junk-id>1</junk-id>
        <junk-ip-address>1.2.2.3</junk-ip-address>
        <junk-state>success</junk-state>
        <junk-rcvd>158558</junk-rcvd>
        <junk-sent>158520</junk-sent>
        <foobar>
          <id1>1</id1>
          <id2>1</id2>
        </foobar>
      </random>
    </config>}


set doc [dom parse $XML]
set root [$doc documentElement]
set node [$root selectNodes -namespace {x http://random.com/ns/random/config} x:random/x:junk-state ]
puts [$node text]
```

**EDIT**: If you want the namespace of the `<random>` element to be retrieved from the XML automatically you can do it as follows (assuming that `<random>` is the only child of the root element):

```
set doc [dom parse $XML]
set root [$doc documentElement]
set random [$root childNode]
set ns [$random namespace]
set node [$random selectNodes -namespace [list x $ns] x:junk-state]
puts [$node text]
```

Comment: That just worked like a charm!, but is there a way to dynamically construct the namespace part, instead of hard-coding the attribute value of `random` node?

Comment: @Inian, what do you mean by "dynamically construct"? Sure, as with anything in Tcl, you can do `set ns http://whatever.com/foo; set node [$root selectNodes -namespace [list x $ns] x:random/x:junk-state]` but what would that buy you? Or is your intent is to extract the xmlns value from the XML document before querying it? That is, what real problem you intend to solve with a prospective answer?

Comment: @kostix: Am pretty new in `tcl`, learning out its nuances, so what I thought was if suppose the xmlns string could change in the future, then it would make more sense to capture that value and use it inside `xpath` right? Is it making sense?

Comment: This is not really a Tcl "problem", but an XML one.

Comment: @Inian In order to retrieve the `xmlns` value from the `<random>` element you must be able to retrieve that element first, but you cannot do that using any xpath facilities since you don't know its namespace yet! I have updated the answer with one way of doing it.

Comment: @Inian, please note that as far as XML is concerned, two elements with the same local name but different namespaces are completely different. Yeah, I know that massive amounts of crappy XML which ignore this exist in the wild. ;-)